# How to fix an error while to install ngspice in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ngspice

I try to install ngspice in ubuntu but unfortunatelly something went wrong with installation.

Please somebody help me how to fix this issue:

My ubuntu version is 22.04

```
yan13to@mbp:~ $ uname -a
Linux mbp 6.5.0-21-generic #21~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb  9 13:32:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
yan13to@mbp:~ $
```

And problem installation is here:

```
yan13to@mbp:~ $ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libstd-rust-1.74
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ngspice
Suggested packages:
  ngspice-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ngspice
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2.353 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7.972 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 317005 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ngspice_36+ds-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ngspice (36+ds-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ngspice_36+ds-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ngspice/analog.cm', which is also in package libngspice-kicad 0.1-42~202402021044+902a62d2f~ubuntu22.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ngspice_36+ds-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
yan13to@mbp:~ $
```

Comment: [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in) ??